# Iterar array em elemento input

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou precisando gerar um elemento radio de acordo com a seleção de um campo. Estou tendo dificuldades de gerar o bloco:

preciso preencher o value dos radius nesse bloco de acordo com o setamento do do array abaixo:

```
var horario = ['quinta/10:00:00', 'quinta/21:00:00','sexta/10:00:00','domingo/15:00:00']; 

 <div id="valores">
    <input class="sr-only" name="dias" type="checkbox" value="" ><span class="checkbox-label">
    </span></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim, criando os inputs com strings de HTML em JavaScript:

```js
var horario = ['quinta/10:00:00', 'quinta/21:00:00', 'sexta/10:00:00', 'domingo/15:00:00'];

var inputs = horario.map(function(h) {
  return [
    '<input class="sr-only" name="dias" type="checkbox" value="', h, '" />',
    '<span class="checkbox-label">', h, '</span>'
  ].join('');
}).join('<br>');

document.getElementById('valores').innerHTML = inputs;
```

```html
<div id="valores">

</div>
```